# ExpressJs equivalent for Rails object_url

Tags: node.js, express

I'm currently converting my Rails application to ExpressJs. Then I stumbled upon this scenario where an object url is required.

Does express have this kind of helper?

Comment: No, it doesn't. [CompoundJS](http://compoundjs.com/) offers support for [similar helpers](https://github.com/compoundjs/guides/blob/master/basics/crash-course.md#router), though I'm not sure about a generic helper for any given object.

Answer (score 0):

Locomotive http://locomotivejs.org/guide/resources/ has some routing helpers that you could use.